# Travel Visa-Free stopover Guangzhou, multi-city

Tags: visas, china, visa-free-entry, stopovers, guangzhou

Does anyone know if the following itinerary is valid for a visa-free stopover in Guangzhou?

Brisbane, Australia -> Singapore -> Guangzhou -> Brisbane?

If I buy the tickets multi-city will this work? Will it not work if I book it all on Singapore Airlines since technically I'm going through Singapore in order to arrive back home?

Comment: Your only stop in China is Guangzhou -- why wouldn't it be fine?

Comment: Because the technicality is that I'm both arriving from and departing to the same city, except one is only a stop-over for a couple hours, the other is a destination and arrival.

Comment: Why would the Chinese immigration care about the rest of your itinerary though? If the requirements for the transit don't indicate any restrictions of the kind, then there is no issue.

Comment: They would care because it's an easy enough way to evade the 3 city rule, since your final city is never really a certainty as you can just end your trip in Singapore. I guess it's at their discretion, but should be okay.